# How to excape a comma in a pip command in Ansible

Tags: python, pip, ansible

I am running this pip command in Ansible

```
- name: Install airflow
  pip: "name=apache-airflow[async,postgres] state=present"
  environment:
     SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE: yes
     AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE: yes
```

But I receive an error

```
Invalid requirement: 'apache-airflow[async'\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py\", line 82, in __init__\n    req = Requirement(req)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py\", line 96, in __init__\n    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))\nInvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at \"'[async'\"
```

I thought by quoting the pip line it would not try and separate either side of the comma. Is there a way in Ansible to escape the comma or anther way to pass a list of arguments into Airflow install line

Link to the Airflow install documentation https://airflow.apache.org/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

Separating the comand seemed to work.

```
- name: Install airflow async
  pip: name=apache-airflow[async] state=present
  environment:
     SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE: yes
     AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE: yes

- name: Airflow with postgres
  pip:
     name: apache-airflow[postgres]
  environment:
     SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE: yes
     AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply escape it with '\'. Did not test though. Hope it works.

```
- name: Install airflow
  pip: "name=apache-airflow[async\\,postgres] state=present"
  environment:
     SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE: yes
     AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE: yes
```

Comment: Gave it a try and it does not seem to work, I'm not sure if \ is an escape character in yaml

Comment: what is the error message? Can you try with two escape, like '\\,' ?

Comment: It doesn't work as well. It's automatically escaped as `\\\\\`